# Bundler not updating when it says it has in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, best-in-place

I am using the best_in_place gem. Unfortunately, the update code on the gem was not working properly but a solution had been found and merged into the latest alpha version of the gem. Initially I simply edited the gemfile and added the fix but I know that is bad practice so I added:

```
gem 'best_in_place', github: 'bernat/best_in_place'
```

to get the latest version. I bundle installed and it said this:

```
Using best_in_place (3.0.0.alpha) from git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place.git (at master)
```

But, when I go and look at the actual file it has not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle update best_in_place` to update to the latest commit.